# grails 2.5.4 won't start from terminal StackOverflowError

Tags: grails

I'm running grails 2.5.4(I cannot upgrade the version), it successfully runs in my IDE (intellij) but I cannot get any grails command to run from the terminal. Even if I type just "grails" and nothing else, it will throw an error.

The error is:`Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"`

I can't seem to get anymore information out of it with --verbose 
Also, I am running java 8

Comment: What operating system? What OS version? Where is grails installed? What version of Java?

Comment: obviously your grails CL installation is broken

Comment: RHEL 7.2, in a folder in root where my applications also reside, oracle 1.8.0.101

Comment: You don't need to post the entire stack which is overflowing, but if you can show enough of the stack to see the repeating cycle, that info might prove helpful.

Comment: that's the thing, I don't have a stack to give. If I did, I could probably figure this out myself. I was hoping that someone else had seen this, the only thing I could find was that this was a problem in like 2.3.3 and was supposedly fixed in 2.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found out what was going on through excessive trial an error. The issue was that I had db2 installed on my machine. I don't know why that was causing the issue. But for anyone that might be running into this issue, that's what the problem was for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem; in our case, all it took was an empty `.inputrc` file in the user's home directory to make grails work.